# is my maxSumDigits method correct?

Tags: java

I created a maxSumDigits method which works off a sumDigits method.
The sumDigits basically returns the sum of its digits. So if you have a number like 650 it would return 11 (6+5+0). 
I have that part created, but it's a two part question and now I have to create a method called maxSumDigits. The maxSumDigits has to return the maximum value of sumDigits(n) for n i nthe range of 1...high. So maxSumDigits(high) to return the values sumDigits(1), sumDigits(2).... all the way to sumDigits(high).

Would this suffice?

```
    public static int maxSumDigits (int high) {
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= high; i++) {
        sum = sumDigits(i);

    }
return sum;     

}
```

I get confused by the question, is it mean't to add up all the results together or just return the highest value for each result?

EDIT:
sumDigits method:

```
public static int sumDigits (int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
        else {
            int hundreds = n / 100;
            int remainder = n % 100;
            int tens = remainder / 10;
            int units = remainder % 10;

            n = hundreds + tens + units;
        return n;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your loop to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= high; i++) {
    sum += sumDigits(i);
}
```

So that you would accumulate the results. This would get you the desired output that you want.

Comment: Oh wait never mind it worked. I had changed the symbol in another method just before. I'll still add my sumDigits code though

Comment: You were missing a plus sign, right ? Nothing else ?

Comment: Yep, I didn't think I had to accumulate the results, I read it as just get the result for each value.

Comment: Such errors can be spotted quickly using a debugger. Consider that for next time; good luck !

Comment: So you really think that a method called `maxSumDigits` should add each single result to a sum?

Comment: @Tom
maxSumDigits for each digit, it's arguable.

Comment: @IceArt A method name like `max...` shows that this method should find a maximum of something, here each single `sumDigits` result. Just adding each result together won't work here. Or the method should be called something like `sumOf...`. Either way, please post the real assignment text (in english) without any interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change:

```
  sum = sumDigits(i);
```

to:

```
  sum += sumDigits(i);
```

This is because the value of sum is over written every time the loop iterates. Instead I assume you want to add the value of sumDigits(i) to sum so, use the operator +=